# Can we make object of an interface in java? If not then why the code below is compiling and showing correct output?

Tags: java, instance

I have learnt that we don't instantiate interfaces but this code is working fine.

Can anyone tell me why is it working?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    public interface lfrag{                        
       public void listen(String s);
    }

    lfrag lis;
}
```

Comment: You are not instantiating anything in your code. You are just declaring a variable of type ```lfrag```

Comment: Related [What does it mean to “program to an interface?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Here you are just declaring the interface type (lfrag lis;) but not instantiating. Instantiating would be lfrag lis = new ClassImplementIfragInterface(); You cannot do lfrag lis = new lfrag lis();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snipped below, you only print out `Hello world!`:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Although you do have an interface `lflag`, you do not **instantiate** anything created inside of it, you only **declare** `lfrag lis`, which does not affect your code.

If you tried to declare `lfrag lis = new lfrag()`, you would have gotten an error - you **cannot** create an object of an interface. What you can do instead is, create a class and then implement an interface on it - this will allow you to override methods from that class in your interface.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your answer if you also added the actual declaration

Answer (score 0):

You're not 'making an object'. You're just declaring a variable without initializing it. Creating variables of interface types is the use case for interfaces, so sure you can do that.

Definige a variable is making use of the contract that you created while definig the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Lfrag lis;

Here you are creating a reference variable of type Lfrag which is allowed.Reference variables are used to access objects in the heap memory(created by new).